# Run function onscroll, unless parent has class in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm puzzled; I have a `window.onscroll = function() { .. }` which works fine, except for some cases. In these cases, the `<html>` element has one of two specific classes. So that seems easy enough; don't run the `onscroll` if either of those classes exist. But, how?

Roughly, I have this set up;

```
if (!html.classList.contains('firstClass') && !html.classList.contains('secondClass')) { 
   window.onscroll = function() { ... }
}
```

But the `onscroll` function runs every time. I've also tried to put the `if` statement inside the `onscroll`, but no luck.
Now I'm unsure if the markup of the `if` statement is correct. So I've also tried in in a simpler fashion, where the statement is always true or false;

```
if (html.classList.contains('thirdclass') { }
```

In this example, the code either runs or it doesn't, no matter if the class gets added or removed. It might have to do with how the DOM works, and the `html` element maybe not getting picked up?

I'm unsure if the markup in the `if` statement is even correct; all sources I find on this use jQuery, and none of them clearly state how to run `if (element has one of either two class classes) {}`.

Who can help me get on the right track?

edit:
Well slap me silly. I set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dga9L6kw/6/) to demonstrate, but in there it does work as expected(!). This leaves me to think that it has to do with the ecosystem this code is running in (Magento 2 frontend). Maybe how the js is initialized? (Yes, I do need to call jquery sadly);

```
define([
    "jquery"
  ], 
  function($) {
    "use strict";
    // code here
});
```

Could that be the case?

Comment: I think your second approach is fine and should work: 

window.onscroll = function () {
if (!html.classList.contains('firstClass') && !html.classList.contains('secondClass')) {
// Your code goes here.
   }
};

The problem with the first one is that once html does not have both classes and if evaluates to true, you set the onscroll listener. From then on it automatically picks up all the scroll events, without caring about the if. Can you provide a pen or fiddle with your problems in the second approach ? Hope it helps !

Comment: That's the thing; when I use your example the code runs fine without either class. Then when I add the class to the html element, it still keeps running the code, when it shouldn't.

Comment: Can you try setting break points in the onscroll listener to check whether the html.classList has changed ? Sounds silly, but since your js code runs in an environment, they might evaluate the arrays once and cache them. Check for other onscroll listeners set by them. Maybe they statically evaluate your code and "paste" it in their environment.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, I guess your `html` tag initially dont have the classes `firstClass` and `secondClass`.

So, here the problem is that you are registering an event listener to `onscroll` event only if the `html` element don't have the classes `firstClass` and `secondClass`. As initially it is true (because initially the `html` element doesn't have the class required classes), it will register the event listener and it will always fire whenever you scroll.

Also your code will never fire the event listener if initially the classes are `firstClass` and `secondClass`.

Now, what you need to change to achieve your goal is to add the `if` statement inside the `onclick` listener instead of outside.

Here's the code:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (!html.classList.contains('firstClass') && !html.classList.contains('secondClass')) { 
        // Do stuff
    }
};
```

What the above code does is that it first registers the event listener no matter what the class of the `html` element. But it will execute the code inside the `if` block only if the `html` element don't have both the classes. So, your goal is achieved here.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The `html` doesn't have any class initially. When I put the if statement inside the onscroll the code runs, but it keeps running also if the class is added later, that's what is puzzling me! I'll see if I can make a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Oops! My mistake. I corrected the answer. Still the explanation remains the same.

Comment: Well look at that; in the JSfiddle it does work as expected. I've updated my question, maybe it's the initialization?